# How to Fix File Download From Django App Failure

Tags: python, django

In my django application, the program creates a document and saves it to the file path defined in settings.py MEDIA_URL.  If a file exists, the user should able to click on a link in the template and the file should download.  When I do this, I get a .docx download, but it reads "Failed - No File".

I am noticing two things - 1) the file that downloads immediately is blank when opened. 2) when I look in the folder defined by the file path in settings.py, I can see that the file is there and it is filled out as it should be. Clearly I am doing something wrong in my View, but any ideas what I may be doing wrong? I feel this should be working since I can see the .docx is being generated correctly.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

...

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web_unit')
MEDIA_URL = '/web_unit/'
```

views.py

## creating the .docx file and saving it

```
def docjawn(request):

    reference = request.POST.get('Reference_IDs')
    manifest = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference__reference=reference)
    order = Orders.objects.get(reference=reference)

    doc = DocxTemplate("template.docx")
    totalCNF = 0
    totalFOB = 0
    for item in manifest:
        totalCNF += item.cases * item.CNF
        totalFOB += item.cases * item.FOB
    context = {

        'ultimate_consignee' : order.ultimate_consignee,
        'reference' : order.reference,
        'ship_to' : order.ship_to,
        'terms' : order.terms,
        'date' : "12",
        'ship_date' : "7/4/19",
        'vessel' : order.vessel,
        'POE' : order.POE,
        'ETA' : order.ETA,
        'booking_no' : order.booking_no,
        'manifest' : manifest,
        'totalCNF' : totalCNF,
        'totalFOB' : totalFOB,
}


    doc.render(context)

    doc_io = io.BytesIO()
    doc.save(doc_io)
    doc_io.seek(0)

    # Save the BytesIO to the field here
    order.order_file.save("generated_doc.docx", File(doc_io))

    response = HttpResponse(doc_io.read())
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=generated_doc.docx"
    response["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

    return response
```

index.html

## showing how I have the link to the file url setup in the template

```
  {% for order in orders %}

    <tr>

   ...

      {% if order.order_file %}
        <td><a href="{{ order.order_file.url|default_if_none:'#' }}" download>Download</a></td>
      {% endif %}  
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: look at your source HTML in your browser, what is the href? Since `/web_unit/` is your `MEDIA_URL`, your url should start with */web_unit/*

Comment: @dirkgroten yes when i look at the source HTML from the browser the href is ```<a href="/web_unit/web_unit/generated_doc_CjqA68A.docx" download="">Download</a>``` I don't know where the random string of letters in the file name is coming from, but I do see that file in the folder. Still not downloading.

Comment: what's the full path to this folder? what's the name of `BASE_DIR`? And assuming this is in development, what [urlpattern did you define](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) to tell Django where your media files are located?

Comment: @dirkgroten yes this is in development - full path is: Desktop/WBU/web_unit/web_unit/web_unit   I know this is an odd file path.  And I'm not sure what you mean by what urlpattern I've defined.  I have nothing in my urls.py for this as I couldn't find information on how to set that up - although it seemed strange to me.

Comment: I linked in my comment above to the documentation on how to setup django to serve uploaded files in development. Django needs a url pattern to be able to serve that url. Is WBU the BASE_DIR or WBU/web_unit? (the location of manage.py)

Comment: @dirkgroten ok I just reviewed that briefly. My BASE_DIR is WBU/web_unit. All I need to do then is to add the snippet ```+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)``` at the end of urls.py?

Comment: yes, although I would wrap that in a `if settings.DEBUG` since you don't want that in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to precede your media urls always with the `MEDIA_URL`. The urls saved for a `FileField` are always relative to the `MEDIA_ROOT`. And `MEDIA_URL` points to `MEDIA_ROOT` so you should add that:

```
href="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ order.order_file.url }}"
```

Also you need to configure Django so that the development server knows what to do when it encounters a url starting with `MEDIA_URL` as [described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).